# Get correct image orientation property from photolibrary image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimageorientation

In my iPhone application I take an image with UIImagePickerController from PhotoLibrary. How can I get correct imageOrientation property?

**Update** In any case I get  UIImageOrientationUp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009522/uiimagepickercontroller-check-if-returned-image-is-in-landscape-or-portrait

Comment: in any case I get  UIImageOrientationUp!

Comment: You can check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083293/after-getting-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-uiimageview-rotates-image-for/38135833#38135833

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImageOrientation imageOrientation = image.imageOrientation;

    }
```

Comment: I always get  UIImageOrientationUp

Answer (score 0):

USE this method like for image named "image1"

[self checkImageOrientaionImage:image1];

Method:

```
-(void)checkImageOrientaionImage:(UIImage*)image
{

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)
    {
        NSLog(@"portrait");
    }
   else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
       NSLog(@"landscape");
    }
```

}

Comment: my question is that it is not possible to get correct image orientation of image from photolibrary

Comment: You can check the orientation first and then rotate it according to your suitability.

Comment: If I take image from PtotoLibrary I get UIImageOrientationUp in any case

Comment: if there is anything more you want please mention in detail with example dear.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I only need to get correct image orientation)

Comment: See mine new answer dear.

Answer (score 0):

Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

As per the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)

Check this question also:
[Stack over flow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618546/force-landscape-orientation-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score -1):

Write this code in your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method

Get the `UIImage` from the info dictionary .

And then use this         `UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;`

Comment: there is no such key at all!